# Determining the size of subspaces $\{S_1,…,S_m\}$,$\{T_1,…,T_n\}$ given the fact if they intersect or not

Tags: linear-algebra

In my problem, I have two inputs: a binary matrix $M$ of size $m\times n$ and an integer $k\geq 1$.

Let $S_i$ and $T_j$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $1\leq\dim(S_i)\leq k$ and $1\leq\dim(T_j)\leq k$ for all $i=1,...,m$ and $j=1,...,n$.

The matrix $M$ indicates how the subspaces $S_i$ and $T_j$ must intersect.
When $M(i,j)=0$, it means that $S_i$ and $T_j$ are orthogonal to each other, that is, $S_i\perp T_j$.
When $M(i,j)=1$, it means that $S_i$ and $T_j$ are not orthogonal, that is, $S_i\not\perp T_j$.

> My question is the following: given an integer $k$ and a matrix $M$, what can we say about the dimensions of the subspaces?

For example, it is obvious that when $M(i,j)=0$, it leads to the inequality $\dim(S_i)+\dim(T_j)\leq k$ meaning that we can obtain stronger upper bounds:  $\dim(S_i)\leq \color{red}{k-1}$ and $\dim(T_j)\leq \color{red}{k-1}$.

My problem concerns more particularly the following example with $k=3$ and $M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$,

I am pretty sure it is necessary to have $\dim(S_i)=\dim(T_j)=1$ for $i,j=1,...4$ but I am not able to prove it.

Maybe, with this special sparsity pattern of $M$ (multiple zeros per row/column), would it possible to show that it implies $\dim(S_i)\leq k-2$ and $\dim(T_j)\leq k-2$ for $i,j=1,...4$?

Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: Also posted to mathoverflow, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252065/determining-the-size-of-subspaces-s-1-s-m-t-1-t-n-given-their without notification to either site.

Answer (score 0):

they are not all of dim 1, because if $dim S_i = dim T_j = 1$ then $S_i = T_j$ if they intersect non-trivially. And hence $S_1 = T_1$ and $ S_1 = T_4$ but $S_2 \cap T_1 \neq 0 $ and $S_2 \cap T_4 =  0 $

Comment: Yes, my description was wrong, I am really sorry. When $M(i,j)=0$, we must have $S_i\cap T_j=\emptyset$ and when $M(i,j)=1$, $S_i\cap T_j\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Do you mean $S_i \cap S_j = 0$? Both are subspaces and hence contain $0$

Comment: Yes, indeed, sorry again.